# Hide output if variable don't have data PHP

Tags: php

I made this:

```
 global $product;
 $koostis = $product->get_attribute( 'color' );

 echo "<h2>Color: ".$koostis."</h2>";
```

This show a color attribute on my product.

But if a product don't have a color attribute this script show only: "Color:" of course.

I try to use:

```
if (isset($koostis)) {
echo "<h2>Color: ".$koostis."</h2>";
}
```

But don't work because the variable is not exactly empty, i need a method to hide `echo "<h2>Color: ".$koostis."</h2>";` if the variable not contain data.

Exist?

Comment: Try if($koostis ==null)

Comment: Check if isset and not empty $ koostis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the variable is blank, you can check for that with `empty`:

```
if (!empty($koostis)) {
    echo "<h2>Color: ".$koostis."</h2>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for not empty without any funciton:

```
if ($koostis) {
    echo "<h2>Color: ".$koostis."</h2>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $koostis != "" ? "Color:" . $koostis : "";
```

Comment: Whats wrong with this answer I thing its same as other answers by using tarnary just missing h2 tag

Comment: Don't know. Works fine and is more straight forward then to add 3 lines of code just for a simple task like this